# JavaScript - ForEach

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript array of objects. Something like this:

```
var people = [
  { id:1, firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Smith' },
  { id:2, firstName: 'Bill', lastName: 'Smith' }
];
```

I am iterating through the people using `forEach`. Here is my code:

```
function doSomething() {
  people.forEach(function(person, self) {
    self.helpPerson(person);
  }, this);
}

function helpPerson(person) {
  alert('Welcome ' + person.firstName);
}
```

I am trying to call `helpPerson` from within the `forEach` loop. However, when I attempt to call it, I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: self.helpPerson is not a function
```

If I add `console.log(self);`, "0" gets printed to the console window. This implies that I'm not passing in my parameter correctly. Or, I'm misunderstanding closures (just when I thought I fully understood it :)).

So, why doesn't `self` exit?

Comment: what do you like to achieve with self?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to invoke helpPerson with a `this`, `self`, or any other context. Just invoke it directly:

```
var people = [
  { id:1, firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Smith' },
  { id:2, firstName: 'Bill', lastName: 'Smith' }
];

function doSomething() {
  people.forEach(function(person) {
    helpPerson(person);
  });
}

function helpPerson(person) {
  alert('Welcome ' + person.firstName);
}
```

When you log `self` to the console you are seeing "0" because it is printing the index of the loop iteration.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for forEach to see what callbacks are passed to it's `forEach` function.

Typically, `self` is used to capture a context in a closure (`var self = this;`). Please see the [related links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1) to this question because that is a very important concept.

Answer (score 0):

`helpPerson` is a global variable, not a property of the array.

`self.helpPerson(person);` should be `helpPerson(person);`

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` passes two arguments to the callback: the item being iterated and its index. That's why console is logging 0.

You are expecting `this` to pass as an argument, when it's actually more magical than that. You can use `this` inside the callback and it will use the context of whatever `this` you passed as an argument to the `forEach`

```
function doSomething() {
  people.forEach(function(person, index) {
    this.helpPerson(person); //Or for brevity, you can just remove `this` here
  }, this);
}

function helpPerson(person) {
  alert('Welcome ' + person.firstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` takes 2 parameters : a function(val, index, arr) and a this binding argument .

```
 people.forEach(function(person, self) {
    self.helpPerson(person); // self here would be array index number
  }, this);
```

the way you've defined `helpPerson()` you can call it directly like  `helpPerson(person);`

Answer (score 0):

Please see comments

```js
var people = [
    { id:1, firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Smith' },
    { id:2, firstName: 'Bill', lastName: 'Smith' }
];

function doSomething() {
    people.forEach(function(person) { // no parameter for index required
        helpPerson(person);           // just call the function
    });                               // no other parameter is required
}

function helpPerson(person) {
    alert('Welcome ' + person.firstName);
}

doSomething();
```